# Change div background color based on text inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On [this site](https://dev.infinitypxl.com/americar/) I have a "status tag" (Diesel, Auto, Manual, etc) on each inventory picture. I want the background color of that tag to be changed based on the text that is within the DIV.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var text = $('.image-container>.status-tag').text().toLowerCase(), color;
    switch (text) {
     case 'Diesel':
        color = '#ff0000';
        break;
     case 'AUTO':
        color = '#6dc8bf';
        break;
     default:
        color = '#39d52d';
    }
    $('.image-container>.status-tag').css('background', color);
});
</script>
```

The default color is showing up, but for some reason, I cannot get the specified color to show based on the text inside the div.

This is not my own code, I found it on another thread[(original code here)](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/uJwE6/), but can't seem to get it to work on my site. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does the text in the `div` change? When does that happen?

Comment: Upon first inspection, it seems like the switch will never match with `Diesel`or `AUTO`because of your `toLowerCase`. If you change them to `diesel` with small d and `auto`, all lowercase, you might have some luck.

Comment: the status tag has the same css class (.status-tag) for all of them. I am able to choose what the text is inside the div, so when I have "auto", I want red for example, or when it is "manual", it should be purple for example.

Comment: it seems you copied the code and you simply replace text by your own without paying attention to lowercase as @MichaelEvans said

Comment: @MichaelEvans it doesn't matter if i use caps or not, it still does not work. If you look at the original code, you change it to upper or lower case and it still works.

Comment: Have you tried `'background-color'` instead of `'background'`?

Comment: @NicoBach inside the switch, or in the status tags themselves?

Comment: Also, what others have said about your switch statement is correct. You're comparing an all-lowercase value to `case` statements containing text with non-lowercase characters. This will never evaluate correctly. Modify your switch statement to use all-lowercase strings.

Comment: @MichaelEvans, not sure what the switch is. :/ not a dev, still a noob and learning. but the text is within the div itself: Screenshot here: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2951771/bd78112d5e5d41c185f386e118ef348a

Comment: @NicoBach take a look at my answer to see what I mean. Also consider the answer from marcobiedemann , that looks nice and concise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
    //var text = $('.image-container>.status-tag').text().toLowerCase(), color;
    $('.image-container>.status-tag').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).text());
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
     switch (text) {
      case 'diesel':
        color = '#ff0000';
        break;
      case 'auto':
        color = '#6dc8bf';
        break;
      default:
        color = '#39d52d';
     }
     $(this).css('background', color);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
 <div class="image-container">
   <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Diesel</div>
   <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">AUTO</div>
   <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Bleh</div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Here is your scenario in a runnable example that gives you what you are after. Like others have said, your switch cases need to match the text (you are using toLowerCase() but still trying to compare it with text with capital letters like 'Diesel' and 'AUTO'). But also, if you have multiple .image-container>.status-tag you will get back a string of all text in your original text variable. In the example I posted, you would get dieselautobleh from `$('.image-container>.status-tag').text().toLowerCase()` which is why you are still getting the default color,

Therefore, I used a a .each(function(){}); on it to deal with each image container on its own.

Edit for comments about style not applied after ajax call:

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  //all your ajax stuff
  //This is where complete would go, like:
  complete: function(){
    //do your stuff
  }
}).done(function() {//a done handler to manage when the ajax call is done
  $('.image-container .status-tag').each(function(){
  //do your switch stuff to change color just like before
  });
});
```

From further looking, the complete I told you might work, but .done might be better to handle that (don't put in both a complete and a .done).

Comment: Tyler, you are awesome man! that did exactley what I needed! Thank you soo much! I was at it for hours, hoping to solve the issue myself. Figured it was time for help. thanks again!

Comment: Hey @TylerDahle, quick question...if i have 2 classes assigned to a div, how would i target it? I've tried

$('.col-sm-5.col-results>.status-tag').each(function(){

But that didnt seem to work. This is the HTML

<div class="col-sm-5 col-results"><div class="status-tag">Auto</div></div>

Thanks

Comment: Your approach is correct. You'd do $('.first-class.second-class>.child-ele.second-child-class'). I added those to the example I made and it worked as expected. You don't need to use all classes in an element when selecting one, unless you need that level of exactness. You should be able to just grab $('.col-results'). Also, do you have any runnable example with your element selection not working?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TylerDahle, I was able to achieve it like this

 $('.col-results .status-tag').each(function(){

But now I ran into another issue (figures, right?) The page that I'm applying all this too, has a search feature that loads the results via ajax. Once the results load, the code is no longer applied. How would I tell it to reapply the code after the results are loaded?

Comment: Without a sample, I am just guessing what is occurring, but I believe: when someone searches, new results are loaded, but the .each() with the switch function is not run on these, so no styling occurs. Ajax has a 'complete' option that you can set a function to. On complete, insert your html (or however you are getting it on the page), then rerun the .each() to style each element properly. (This is my guess at what to do based on what I gather from your last comment, hopefully its on the mark). This page gives info on ajax complete: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: too be honest, that seems over my head at this point. haha.

The page is here dev.infinitypxl.com/americar/full-inventory

As you can see there, the colors are being applied to the banners on each vehicle image. After doing a search on the left for BMW (nothing else)  the results load, but the code is no longer being applied. I really appreciate your help with this issue. :D

Comment: and excuse the slow load times currently, my host is having some issues :/

Comment: Try adding the .each(function(){}) at the end of the ajax complete function (just add another option in ajax -> `complete: function(){ the .each() function here}`. It really does seem like you run that on page load, but then when new elements are added via ajax, they don't get the benefit of the styling because it is not ran again.

Comment: Like so:
`<script>
$(function() {
    complete: function(){
    $('.col-results .status-tag').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).text());
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
     switch (text) {
      case 'auto':
        color = 'rgba(245, 36, 88, 0.8)';
        break;
      default:
        color = 'tranparent';
  }
     $(this).css('background', color);
    });
  });
});
</script>`

Comment: Yes, but move the entire complete: function(){all your code} into the ajax call and make the complete another field in the ajax call.

Comment: I just added an edit that shows how to set up the complete or .done in your ajax call. I think .done is actually better to utilize then complete? I was seeing that complete was supposed to be deprecated.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to apply it today.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, now in the form of an answer for clarity. In your variable definition of `text` you are taking whatever the text is and turning it all lower case (a good idea, in most peoples' books), so that in your markup, you can use any combination of lower and uppercase letters and it will still work. But *because of this* you need to present them as all lowercase in the switch, in order for them to match properly (switch statements need an exact match to work).

```
$(function() {
    var text = $('.image-container>.status-tag').text().toLowerCase(), color;
    switch (text) {
     case 'diesel': // change here
        color = '#ff0000';
        break;
     case 'auto': // and change here
        color = '#6dc8bf';
        break;
     default:
        color = '#39d52d';
    }
    $('.image-container>.status-tag').css('background', color);
});
```

Comment: That makes sense. I have switched them all to lowercase, but still, only that default color is being applied.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:**

1. move script to the end of the body tag
2. use each on status flags
3. lowercase your switch statements too

Your script lives in the head section, so it may be executed before the body is rendered and in that case it will never find your elements. so put it at the end of the body section.

also you use the jquery element selector so you get back an array of elements, not a single one. you have to check them all. a each should do the trick, smth like that (also match your switch cases to lower case, else there will be no match):

```html
$(function() {
    var textElements = $('.image-container>.status-tag'), color;
    
    textElements.each(function(index, element){
      var text = $(element).text().toLowerCase();

    switch (text) {
         case 'diesel':
            color = '#ff0000';
            break;
         case 'auto':
            color = '#6dc8bf';
            break;
         default:
            color = '#39d52d';
        }
      $(element).css('background', color);
    })
    
    
});
```