# Conditional class based on text inside of div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which prints a status based on I word I add in a custom post type I created in WP, I was looking to add a .class based on the content text of the DIV, I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190763/change-div-background-color-based-on-text-inside-div) which changes the style (background color) but I am wondering if it's possible to change the .class instead of just changing a style attribute like in the example which changes just the background color.

Here's the example code from there:

```
    $(function() {
    //var text = $('.image-container>.status-tag').text().toLowerCase(), color;
    $('.image-container>.status-tag').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        switch (text) {
        case 'diesel':
        color = '#ff0000';
        break;
        case 'auto':
        color = '#6dc8bf';
        break;
        default:
        color = '#39d52d';
        }
        $(this).css('background', color);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
 <div class="image-container">
   <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Diesel</div>
   <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">AUTO</div>
   <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Bleh</div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

By default, the "status" word includes this class "pt-cv-ctf-value" so I guess it should be added with that one.

This is the closest I've been of a solution but don't know how to implement it for my case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely move these to CSS classes and then use [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to append these classes to the respective elements.

So what am doing in the below example is, instead of using `.css()` to assign the `background-color`, I am using `.addClass()` method to assign the `class` instead. Note that you can also achieve the above using custom `data-` attributes instead of classes, but it's just a matter of choice.

Also note that I am using `background` so it will override any `background-image` or `background-color` you've set as it's a short-hand. You can explicitly use these properties instead if required.

Expanding my explanation further on the below code which I've refactored a bit. Here, instead of using `switch-case` which might get ugly as and when you start adding more items, I've created a simple object instead to map the words with the `class` names. Later, am using a ternary operator and using the words as the object keys which later will return the desired `class`. If the key doesn't exist, I assume that it's `default`.

```js
$(function() {
  var mapTags = {
    diesel: 'tag-red',
    auto: 'tag-cyan',
    uncategorized: 'tag-green'
  };

  $('.image-container > .status-tag').each(function() {
    var elm = $(this), t = elm.text().toLowerCase();
        elm.addClass(mapTags[t] ? mapTags[t] : mapTags.uncategorized);
  });
});
```

```css
.tag-green {
  background: #39d52d;
}

.tag-red {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.tag-cyan {
  background: #6dc8bf;
}

.status-tag {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="status-tag">Diesel</div>
  <div class="status-tag">AUTO</div>
  <div class="status-tag">Bleh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, everyone suggested the addClass but I'm accepting yours as it had an extended explanation which helps a noob like :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `addClass` to add classes over your element.
Try below code

```js
$(function() {
  //var text = $('.image-container>.status-tag').text().toLowerCase(), color;
  $('.image-container>.status-tag').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    switch (text) {
      case 'diesel':
        className = 'diesel-color';
        break;
      case 'auto':
        className = 'auto-color';
        break;
      default:
        className = 'default-color';
    }
    $(this).addClass(className);
  });
});
```

```css
.diesel-color{
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.auto-color{
  background-color: #6dc8bf;
}

.default-color{
  background-color: #39d52d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Diesel</div>
  <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">AUTO</div>
  <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Bleh</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addClass` jquery method

```js
$(function() {
  //var text = $('.image-container>.status-tag').text().toLowerCase(), color;
  $('.image-container>.status-tag').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    switch (text) {
      case 'diesel':
        className = 'diesel';
        break;
      case 'auto':
        className = 'auto';
        break;
      default:
        className = 'defaultClass';
    }
    $(this).addClass(className);
  });
});
```

```css
.diesel {
  background-color: blue;
}

.auto {
  background: red;
}

.defaultClass {
  background: #39d52d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Diesel</div>
  <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">AUTO</div>
  <div class="status-tag" style="height:50px;width:50px;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Bleh</div>
</div>
```